# Mixed-mode stream-oriented JSON parsing with Moshi without special type adapters

Tags: json, moshi

In Java I want to parse a really long JSON file (an array of objects) using Moshi. I don't want to read the entire file in memory; rather I want to detect each object and then read and process each object one at a time as the stream is parsed. I don't want to create a special `FooBar` class; I just want to parse each object as as some sort of name/value pairs (e.g. a `Map<String, ?>`).

I've read this is [possible with Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming). I've also read that Moshi borrowed from Gson, and even that [Moshi's streaming support is similar to that of Gson](https://bladecoder.medium.com/advanced-json-parsing-techniques-using-moshi-and-kotlin-daf56a7b963d). But it's hard to find any simple, straightforward, and complete documentation for this.

- The [Moshi main page documentation](https://github.com/square/moshi) only talks about adapters. They mention that Moshi comes with "built-in" JSON adapters for things like primitives, but I don't see any examples of how to use them. If they are built-in, why can't I just call `Moshi.fromJson()` and get back some "generic" representation of the data?
- Take a cue from the Gson documentation, I looked at the Moshi [`JsonReader`](https://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/moshi/com.squareup.moshi/-json-reader/index.html) API. It says to start by calling `JsonReader.of(BufferedSource)`. But how do I create a `BufferedSource` from an `InputStream` (or `Path` or `Reader`)? Absolutely no links to the `BufferedSource` API docs, and the Moshi Maven dependencies for `BufferedSource` apparently aren't distributed with the source (as is standard practice on Maven). Maybe it's part of that Okio stuff.
- The `JsonReader` API docs say to call `beginObject()` to manually parse through each object. But the [Gson streaming documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) talks about "mixed reads", where I can use streaming parsing to find an object, and then parse the object in one swoop without manually stepping through the object. But there is no mention in the Moshi docs I've found for these "mixed reads".

I could go on. I could (and will) go spend hours digging for more information and experimenting. But surely someone has documented this before? If not, if someone could give a short, complete explanation and example here, I would imagine it would help not me but others trying to track down the same info.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the incomplete answer, but this is too long for a comment. Hope something here helps.

Moshi assumes familiarity with Okio (a tiny bytes library that powers a lot of JVM and Android programs). Okio is a transitive dependency of Moshi. You can get a BufferedSource from an InputStream with Okio.buffer(Okio.source(is)).

Moshi has an object-mapping API (JsonAdapter) and an underlying streaming/encoding/decoding API (JsonReader, JsonWriter). JsonAdapters can be grabbed off the Moshi object with moshi.adapter(someType). They are meant to be cached (that's why there's no short Moshi.fromJson()).

It sounds like you want to use the JsonReader API. It's basically the same as the Gson API but just powered by Okio. Moshi's JsonReader also has a `readJsonValue()` if you want to created a raw Java type representation of the JSON (e.g. JSON object is Map<String, Object>, JSON array is List, JSON primitives are Java primitives)

Lastly, the examples are a good place to look for usage patterns: https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes

If you have a specific question or test case you're trying to run, I'm sure someone's around who can help.